# how to create multiple branches in git as orphans and work with different branches simultaneously?

Tags: git, github

I want to create multiple unique branches and want to code in these branches simultaneously. I want to use two different text editors, one for frontend and other for backend. whenever I am changing branch in first text-editor its changing the branch automatically in the other text-editor.

I want like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu-q2zYwEYs. Like how he's creating different unique branch for different lessons and I want to do likewise.

For Eg, I need to create 2 different branches frontend and backend (here both are unique as both have different packages and working environment). and I want to checkout frontend branch in say, vs-code and backend branch in say, atom and I should be able to work simultaneously

What I have tried so far :

**Approach 1**

```
git init
git checkout --orphan frontend
git rm -rf .

git checkout --orphan backend
git rm -rf .
```

This creates two unique branches, I agree. But I couldn't checkout both the branches simultaneously. As I told above, I need to work in frontend branch in vs-code and backend branch in atom simultaneously but I couldn't.

**Approach 2**

```
git worktree add server
```

When I am trying this, I am getting the following error :

```
Preparing worktree (new branch 'server')
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'HEAD'.
```

So , if anyone wish to help, please try to include a working example and before marking as duplicate or flagging the question, please tell in comments/answer so I can try first. If I find as duplicate, I myself will delete :)

Comment: using worktree is correct. you just need to find out why you get error ```fatal: Not a valid object name: 'HEAD'.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> git init
> git checkout --orphan frontend
> git rm -rf .
>
> git checkout --orphan backend
> git rm -rf .
> ```
>
> This creates two unique branches ...

Actually, it doesn't.  (Well, this depends on whether you did anything else too.)

In particular, if you just did that in an otherwise empty directory, you now have a completely empty Git repository, with *no commits and no branches*.

> ```
> Preparing worktree (new branch 'server')
> fatal: Not a valid object name: 'HEAD'.
> ```

This is just what you'd see in that situation.

The fundamental problem here is simple: Git *cannot* have any branches in a repository that has no commits.  The reason for this is that a *branch name* holds the hash ID of some existing, valid commit.<sup>1</sup>

The curious thing about initializing a new empty Git repository is that `git status` will tell you that you are on some branch—yet we've just proven that no branches *exist*:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

If we use `git branch` to list out all branches, this helps confirm the lack of branches.  The `git symbolic-ref HEAD` command will show what's in `HEAD`, but `git rev-parse HEAD`, which will show the hash ID of the current commit, fails:

```
$ git branch
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

This shows us that, in fact, we have no branches.  Using `git checkout` or `git switch` to create a new orphan branch "works", but doesn't actually *create* any branch either:

```
$ git checkout --orphan xyzzy
Switched to a new branch 'xyzzy'
$ git branch
```

There are still no branches.

Before we can create *any* branches, we must create our first commit.  This is one reason GitHub will, when you create a new repository, make an initial commit in it *for* you, so that you don't ever have to deal with this wacky situation in which you're on a branch that doesn't exist.  So let's create our initial commit for our now-current branch `xyzzy`:

```
$ echo xyzzy branch > afile
$ git add afile
$ git commit -m 'initial commit on xyzzy'
[xyzzy (root-commit) b1bab83] initial commit on xyzzy
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 afile
$ git branch
* xyzzy
```

It's the act of *making the commit* that creates the branch.  Now that we have one commit—in my case, `b1bab83`—we can create as many branch names as we like.  *All* of them *must* refer to this one commit!  That's the only commit we have, so *every* branch name *must* use this hash ID.

If you'd like to create a second *root commit*, rather than a commit that comes after the (single) existing root commit, **this** is when `git checkout --orphan` becomes useful.  When we're in that special state, on an unborn branch as we were in the initially totally-empty repository, asking for a new branch name doesn't do any good, but when we're in a more normal state, on some existing branch, the usual way of creating a *new* branch name will use the *current commit's hash ID* for the new name.

Let's see this in action:

```
$ git checkout --orphan plugh
Switched to a new branch 'plugh'
$ git branch
  xyzzy
$ git status
On branch plugh

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   afile
```

There's just the one branch, `xyzzy`, in this repository.  Our *new* branch, `plugh`—well, we're "on" branch `plugh`, but it *does not exist (yet)*.  This is the same state we had a moment ago when there were no commits at all.  Note the `No commits yet` part of the `git status` output: that's because the current branch doesn't exist.  The `changes to be committed` say that we'll create one new file named `afile`, because the *index / staging area* is still held over from before.  We can remove it all, and make a different file and add that and then commit, to create our new root commit:

```
$ git rm -rf .
rm 'afile'
$ echo plugh branch > zfile
$ git add zfile
$ git commit -m 'initial commit on plugh'
[plugh (root-commit) 2bca2d3] initial commit on plugh
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 zfile
$ git branch
* plugh
  xyzzy
```

We now have *two* branches, unrelated to each other; each branch name holds the hash ID of a root commit, with `plugh` holding (in this case) `2bca2d3` (any commits you make will have a different hash ID of course).

Now that we have two commits, we can make any number of new branch names *and* choose *either* of these two commits for those branch names to name.

Remember: Git is all about *commits*.  Branch names, when and if you use them at all, are just there to help you (and Git) *find* commits.  A branch name stores the hash ID of *one* commit.  That commit must exist; that commit is the *last* commit on that branch.

Multiple names can (and fairly often *do*) hold the same hash ID.  But until you have some commits, you cannot have *any* names at all.  Moreover, if you want two names to identify two different hash IDs, you must have at least two different commits in your repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>The phrase "existing, valid commit" is redundant as there is no such thing as an existing but invalid commit.  I just wrote this as emphasis: for a branch name to exist in a Git repository, it must hold the hash ID of a commit.  When there are no commits, there are no hash IDs *of* commits either.

Comment: wow, thanks for such a detailed explanation  <3